# convert this string into decimal

Tags: c#

Sounds easy but when I tried to achieve i'm stock about how is the formatter to make this conversion this are some examples of strings that i need to convert to decimal

```
00.24
48.34
01.24
```

Does anybody know how can i Accomplish this?? I tried like this

```
try
{
   decimal x =  Convert.ToDecimal("00.24", );
   //Which formatter do I need to pass??
   decimal x =  Convert.ToDecimal("00.24", Formatter???);
}
Catch(Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception()
}
```

But It doesn't work because the result it's 24D and i need 0.24D

Comment: Have you tried `Decimal.Parse()`?

Comment: Don't throw a new exception in the catch block, it makes you lose the original exception information

Comment: @p.campbell, Decimal.Parse will have the same effect as Convert.ToDecimal...

Comment: I have to vote this question down for the incomplete code. You could have easily looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw for additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect your system culture is not English and has different number formatting rules. Try passing the invariant culture as the format provider:

```
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal("00.24", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You could also use `Decimal.Parse`:

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("00.24", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `Decimal.Parse`

```
decimal x = Decimal.Parse("00.24");
Console.WriteLine(x);  // Prints: 00.24
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Decimal.TryParse should work. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The result you're getting is because the dot `.` is tretaed as a group (thousand) separator. the parser simply discards it, and doesn't check if the group sizes are right. So '20.100.200'  or  '1.2.3.4' would also get parsed as 20100200 and 1234.

This happens on many european cultures, like 'es'

You have to use any culture that doesn't consider a `.` as a group separator, but as a decimal separator. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is one of the possible cultures (it has basically the same configuration of en-US).