# Why double.Parse("0.05") returns 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, double

I am reading a value from my App.config; which is:

```
 <add key="someValue" value="0.05"/>
```

And I try to convert it to double by doing:

```
 var d = double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someValue"]);
```

And I obtain 5.0 insteads of 0.05.

Can you advice? What do I do wrong and how should I parse this?

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721950/double-parse-internationalization-problem

Comment: I suggest using `public static double Parse(string s,NumberStyles style,IFormatProvider provider)` instead. What exactly happens when you set a `string` variable to `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someValue"]` it seems you have not really tried to debug your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's for your culture settings, Test the same but with a comma instead a point and you will see that work's

```
var d = double.Parse("0,05");
```

To fixed this problem you could used the follow overload of the parse function

```
var d = double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someValue"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: First that doesn't mean that i copy that, second i have question that i made few month ago with this problem. Because in my country We used the comma instead the point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507759/convert-this-string-into-decimal. And Second when i edited my answer i was looking for the answer in that question to see the correct syntax for the overload

Comment: @Jorge - So either way you just quoted somebody else and changed the values.  Besides it would be much better to use the `public static double Parse( string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)` in a case like this.

Comment: @Jorge: That's fine, but you should reference the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the problem is in the culture settings. There could be many issues with them, such as comma as digital separator. When you're working with non-cultured values, such as config files, you should explicitly specify that you need InvariantCulture. Try

```
var d = double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someValue"],
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: because some cultures treat `,` as fraction separator (decimal mark) and `.` as separator of every 3 digits

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo {
    NumberGroupSeparator = ".",
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
};
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("0.05", nfi));
```

prints `5` as well, so the problem is in your culture settings.

Try

```
var d = double.Parse(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someValue"], 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always pass your culture info when using double.Parse. Here in Belgium, it's "0,05".

Answer (score -1):

It's because of culture settings. Please ensure "." is a delimiter in your current culture.