# Input string was not in a correct format when converting to integer

Tags: c#

In line:

```
int d = Convert .ToInt32 ( TxtAmount.Text);
```

there is an error

> Input string was not in a correct format

I want to convert the number inside `TxtAmount.Text`. if it's a negative number to decimal or integer without `-` and then convert it again to string because `ConvertNumbersToArabicAlphabet` the parameter is string.

```
int d = Convert .ToInt32 ( TxtAmount.Text);
ConvertNumbersToArabicAlphabet a = new ConvertNumbersToArabicAlphabet(d.ToString());
Label2.Text = a.GetNumberAr();
```

Comment: What is value of TxtAmount.Text ?

Comment: try using `decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(TxtAmount.Text);`

Comment: And why do you want to convert string to number and then convert that number to string? Just use `new ConvertNumbersToArabicAlphabet(TxtAmount.Text);`

Comment: What is the value of `TxtAmount.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: Possible doublicate ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507759/convert-this-string-into-decimal

Comment: same error , as I told before If the number like -8 for example I want to convert it as 8 then convert it again to string because the parameter in class is string

Comment: @feby - Your question is unclear and your last comment wouldn't cause the issue you are facing... you can just do `abs(d).toString()` when you have the number but that isn't what you are asking. I second Adil's comment, what text are you trying to convert?

Comment: @feby Your `TxtAmount.Text` value is `-8`?

Comment: @Sayse the value TxtAmount.Text = -8  I want to convert it to 8 and then to string the abs dose not exist in current context ,  I added the name space  using System.Math;

Comment: @feby - [It works fine for me](https://ideone.com/fWvQag)..

Answer (score 1):

I'd check whether the input is numeric first and then convert, using `Math.Abs` to make sure the result is always a positive number:

```
int result = 0;

// Does text contain numbers only (and maybe a leading "-")?
if (Regex.IsMatch(TxtAmount.Text, @"^-?[0-9]+$"))
{
    // Try to parse an int from it. If successful, convert it to
    // a positive number in any case (= ignore the leading "-")
    if (Int32.TryParse(TxtAmount.Text, out result))
        result = Math.Abs(result);
}

// In all other cases, the result is 0
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Youse textbox is empty.
check weather your textbox have values or  not

```
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtAmount.Text))
{
   int d = Convert .ToInt32 ( TxtAmount.Text); 
}
```

Comment: As it doesn't work if the text box contains only spaces, it's better to use `if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtAmount.Text))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int d = Convert .ToInt ( TxtAmount.Text);
```

You can use this if you have a Integer Value within the textbox .
If text area contain only a single character then it's not work anymore.

try to put only Integer of same type of data you want to convert in to textbox

like if you want to add a double number then you can use.

```
Double num = Convert .ToDouble ( TxtAmount.Text);
```

if your textbox is empty may sure that you have validation or check for the same:

```
if(TxtAmount.Text==""||TxtAmount.Text=string.Empty)
{
    TxtAmount.Text=0;
}
else
{
  int d = Convert .ToInt ( TxtAmount.Text); 
}
```

Comment: `TxtAmount.Text == ""` and `TxtAmount.Text == String.Empty` are the same thing. It's better to use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtAmount.Text)`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to ignore the negative sign, then you can do string manipulation like:

```
string value = TxtAmount.Text;
if (value.StartsWith("-"))
{
    value = value.Substring(1);
}
```